Facebook Comment Plugin does not display
I use Facebook Comment Plugin but the url in my data-href="" section has the error
"Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'. "
I passing in another url link is fine.
Does anyone know how to fix it???


<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/vi_VN/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v20.0" nonce="k690L44D"></script>
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://geysereco.com" data-width="100%" data-numposts="5"></div>



I followed the instructions pass appID in src="" but it still doesn't work

Have you made sure to follow the guide?

@micahlt I pass another url is work fine. My problem is my website url "https://geysereco.com" and I don't know why my url is deny :(

Are you located outside the United States?  It's possible you're encountering issues caused by Facebook's "Changes to Social Plugins in the European Region" announcement which you can find on the page that I linked above.

How is this problem related to Laravel?
